# Index Notation Divergence of f grad g

Tags: tensors

I'm struggling to figure this out. How do you write this in index notation?

\begin{equation}
\nabla \cdot (f\nabla g)
\end{equation}

I started with $$f\nabla g = f_k \partial_kg_j$$ but when I take the dot product I get
$$ \partial_k f_k \partial_kg_j $$ that's 3 repeated indices. I don't think you can have 3 repeated indices. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

$g$ and $f$ are functions, so you don't have the indices on $f$ or $g$, i.e. 
$f\,\nabla g=f\,\partial_k g$. So when you take divergence, we have 
$\nabla\cdot (f\,\nabla g)=\partial_k(f\,\partial_k g)$.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ and $g$ are scalar fields, so neither has an index.

Try starting with $f \nabla g = f \partial_j g$ and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

By using chain rule I arrived at.
$\nabla\cdot (f\,\nabla g)=\partial_k(f\,\partial_k g) = \partial_k f \cdot \partial_k g + f \partial_k \partial_k g$.

Comment: Yes, that's almost correct. But you miss $f$ in the second term on the right hand side. That is, the second term should be $f\partial_k\partial_kg$, which is equal to $f\Delta g$.